# iCloud photo sharing limit reached -- new photo app

Tags: icloud, photos

I'm running the 10.3 beta on my iMac, using the new photos app.  I imported about 1,300 pics I took over the weekend (live performance) and want to share them online with some people.

First thing I did was create three new albums, one for each of the performances, on my computer.  So far, so good.

Then I used right click to share each album online via iCloud photo sharing.

Now, I'm getting notifications from Photos every 10 seconds or so with the above message. See image below.  It says activity will resume at 11:14 pm.

What gives? I have space on my iCloud account, space I'm paying $10/month for, and I have plenty of available drive space there.  So why aren't the photos uploading, and is there a way to override this strange sharing limit?

[image]

Comment: Can you check what's taking up your storage by going to System Preferences > iCloud and clicking the "Manage..." button in the lower right corner?

Comment: Well I have 250 gb available still.  iPhoto documents currently take up 162 mb of space.  Photo library takes up 228 gb.

Comment: iCloud photo sharing doesn't count towards your storage limit. I suspect you have found the limit that Apple coded in somewhere, but that would be a guess.

Comment: Since it says activity will resume, i'm guessing this is more of a throttle to prevent you from using too much bandwidth at one time.  Can you confirm what happaned when 11:14 was reached?

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure when it happened, as I wasn't at the computer at 11:14, but as of this am all the pics have uploaded.  So yes, apparently it's just a throttle, not a space issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple absolute and rate limits on iCloud photos. See this article for details:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202299

Currently, if I had to guess, you hit one of the 24 hour limits and need do nothing but wait for the time to pass:

```
Maximum combined number of photos and videos from all contributors per shared album, per hour: 1000
Maximum combined number of photos and videos from all contributors per shared album, per day: 10,000
```

However, if you continue to have issues or are getting multiple notifications like your screen shot indicates, there could be a fault in the waiting loop code and you'll want to reach out to AppleCare to have engineering look at your account in particular. That isn't quick, but in the end usually works well if you are patient.

Comment: I encountered that issue when I shared more than 1000 photos at once. I was able to verify that that 1000 photos limit is for a rolling hour, so more photos were able to be added to the shared album every few seconds until everything went through. As @bmike said, just be patient and it will "resolve" itself.