# Can I Share All Photos in iCloud Photo Library to Family Members?

Tags: icloud, photos, family-sharing

With iCloud Photo Library, assuming I have purchased enough storage space to store all my photos, can I then share *all* my photos to other my family members who are using different iCloud accounts?

([This question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178050/icloud-photo-sharing-limit-reached-new-photo-app) seems to imply there is a limit imposed by Apple that is not publicly-known.)

Comment: There is more than one way to do this.  Shared albums are well documented on apples support: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068?locale=en_US

Comment: That help article doesn't solve the problem -- like the OP my wife and I want to maintain our own Apple IDs, and automatically share all of our photos with each other (no manual intervention). There's no way to do that with iCloud Photos, so instead we have a shared Google Photos account and don't use iCloud Photos at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.imore.com/how-use-iclouds-family-sharing-photos-os-x) by Serenity Caldwell of iMore, there are three ways to share photos to all your family members.

1. Use the "Family" album that is automatically created if you have Family Sharing turned on.
2. Create a shared album.
3. Use the same iCloud account for all family members.

Nevertheless, there doesn't seem to be a way to automatically share *all* your photos to your family members. You will still need to copy photos into the share album. (Unless you are all using the same iCloud account, which I didn't want to do, since each user already have their own active iCloud accounts.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that the Family Sharing feature doesn't include the option to share photos and view them in moments, collections, years.

Answer (score 6):

## How many photos and videos can be stored in a shared album?

A shared album can hold a maximum of 5000 photos and videos combined. When you reach your limit, you must delete some photos or videos before adding new ones.

[iCloud Photo Sharing FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786)

[My Photo Stream and iCloud Photo Sharing limits](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202299)

I realize this is not directly answering the original question, but the information seems relevant because if you have > 5k photos/videos then the answer becomes "No, you cannot share **all** iCloud Photo Library content with a family member".

Answer (score 2):

I believe so, just share your apple acount with your family members, and under the same account, all media contents including photos would be uploaded to iCloud and shared among your family member.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems with the Family Share album is that it is limited to 5000 photos...(which my family album already exceeds)

Answer (score -1):

I wish this were as simple as Google Photos make sharing. It is really difficult to leave google photos. They do not make it easy to take your photos and videos. Also, a lot of metadata transfers incorrectly. Then Apple doesn't allow for date metadata to be changed and you need another app to do so individually.

I'm just giving my Apple Id and Password to wife and mom so they can check out any new photos that I take.

Answer (score -2):

Since Apple is not capable and even don't want to solve this issue there is only one solution.
you have to use Google Photos. App is also available in appstore